# SymmetricDS new Dialect

Tags: java, sql, replication, symmetricds

I need to create a new dialect for SymmetricDS to replicate data from MySQl/MSSql/Oracle to new database(there is no dialect for it now). This database has specific sql.
I have read http://www.symmetricds.org/developer/how-to/implement-symmetricds-database-dialect but still don't understand what start with.

Can somebody explain how to create new dialect for SymmetricDS. 
Also I want to modify some data(maybe transform) while I replicate it from current database to my new one.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [issue tracker](http://www.symmetricds.org/issues/view_all_bug_page.php) if there's a plan for implementing the missing dialect. If there's no plan [fork the project on github](https://github.com/JumpMind/symmetric-ds). After checking out the code observe the implementation of supported dialects by searching for classes having 'oracle', 'mysql' or 'postgres' in their names. Choose the dialect closest to the one missing, copy the classes and modify to meet the needs.

Comment: Okay, can I implement some interfaces and abstract classes locally in my project and check that replication works? Or for this I steel need fork all project and implement replication in it?

Comment: as far as I know dialects are not implemented as plugins/extensions. you'll have to work on a fork and contribute back your work

Comment: From http://www.symmetricds.org/developer/how-to/implement-symmetricds-database-dialect - " By writing an implementation for the dialect interfaces, support for a new database can be added to SymmetricDS." - it is not actual now?

Comment: Can't see that the implementation will be picked up automatically from the class path without registering it explicitly within the engine

Comment: Yes, I also can't see this option. So, if I want to do this in my project I need to checkout project implement all methods. And then create jars and add it to my project if I want to do embedded SymmetricDS, or add this jars to installation environment (to libs) if I want to use it as standalone service. Right? Sorry,  for maybe stupid questions :)

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Do not forget to push back the changes to your repo on github and make a pull request. If it's a customer project you're obliged to share the improvements by symmetricDs license.